# AVPlayer IOS dont work when i popped view controller

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have view controller and then i start play audio stream

```
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:info[@"link"]];

playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:soundFileURL];
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:soundFileURL];

[player play];
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

but when i popped this controller player doesn't work
Help me!

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect to happen? Once you popped the controller with the player, the player gets deallocated and released from memory, and therefore cannot play any more.

Comment: Don't pop the controller. Or move the player somewhere out of the controller where it won't be released from the memory, such as a singleton class.

Comment: fix this problem with singleton class but now doesnt work in background(

Comment: Refer to this guide regarding the audio in background: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html